# Can I swap *this itself inside move?

Tags: c++

I have the a **nested** BaseResponse struct inherited by RAII wrapper called Response:

```
struct BaseResponse {
  virtual BaseResponse deep_clone() { /*...*/ }
  virtual void deep_delete() { /*...*/ }
  
  SomeObject *pObj;
};

template <typename T>
class Response : public T
{
public:
    Response() : T() {}
    
    Response(const Response& other) { 
        *this = other.deep_clone();
    }
    
    // the code in question (1)     
    Response(Response&& other) noexcept { 
        std::swap(*this, other);
    }
 
    Response& operator=(Response other) {
        *this = std::move(other);
        return *this;
    }

    // the code in question (2)
    Response& operator=(Response&& other) noexcept {
        std::swap(*this, other);
        return *this;
    }

    virtual ~Response() {
        this->deep_deletion();
    }
};
```

Is my code ok? 
Should I manually do member-wise swap of attributes inherited from BaseResponse? e.g:

```
Response(Response&& other) noexcept { 
    : std::exchange(this->pObj, other.pObj);
}
```

Any other improvements will be welcome, thanks

Comment: I don't see anything here that needs anything beyond declaring an explicit `=default` move constructor, and leaving all other special member functions to their default implementation.

Comment: well, the copy constructor calls a deep_clone(), otherwise it will not deep copy...

Comment: Your move assignment operator calls `swap`, which calls move assignment. I expect an infinite recursion.

Comment: `deep_clone` and `deep_delete` declarations won't compile, as they lack a return type.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik ok, I will change the typo.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik edited the function. now, I'm not sure I understand what you said.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik  ok, you mean that the swap implementation calls std::move internally which calls the operator recursively. do you have a way to solve this?

Comment: Yes, the copy constructor is explicit. This is why the move constructor need to be explicitly `=default`. None of the other special member functions are needed, the default implementations should do their job just fine, by themselves.

Comment: alright, I understand. thanks!

Comment: `*this = other.deep_clone();` won't compile, since `Response::operator=` doesn't take `BaseResponse` as a parameter.

Comment: ok, so I could wrap it in Response<>

Comment: *"Is my code ok?"* -- do you have a reason to think it is not? Stack Overflow is intended to have specific questions, not general "review my code".

Comment: @guy Generally, a solution might be not to use `std::swap`, but to provide a custom `swap` for you class and use it in the move assignment op. Of course, you custom `swap` then must not invoke move assignment of the class object. (Typically, it swaps member variables.)